# Compiling SWF for use in the ADT command

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, adt, packager-for-iphone

I have been using Flash CS5.5 to package Flash for iPhone / Android and now would like to be able to use the latest SDKs that have been available.

There are some options that you can only get from the command line packager 'adt'. I've familiarized myself with this process. It requires a .swf file to input into the packager.

My question is regarding the actual workflow to get the swf compiled with the correct library.
What I think needs to happen is this:

1. overlay the latest SDK in Flash CS5.5 following adobe's steps
2. proceed to publish for iOS or Android
3. wait 5 minutes for that to happen
4. use this .swf compiled with this version of the SDK as the source .swf in the ADT command and use the arguments that I really want (such as apk-captive-runtime) which are not available in the IDE.

Does this sound like the right path to take?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been doing a ton of iOS publishing, so I feel your pain on this one, but it doesn't seem to me that you would need to Publish for iOS in Flash if you are going to do it again using the command-line method. Just include all the proper SDKs and necessary SWCs in the Publish Settings in the FLA, then take that SWF and use it in the command line. Don't sit through the entire IPA publish to use the SWF to do it again command-line.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are right but I'm not sure how to implement that. I'm missing something though. When I publish a swf it is publishing for Flash 11 in the publish settings, but NativeApplication libraries throw a compiler warning.

Comment: What you should try is downloading the latest Flex SDK, go into the Publish Settings of the FLA, click the little wrench icon near the top right of the Publish Settings. Then go to the Library Path tab, and enter something similar to this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\player\11.1` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs`

Comment: That's what I use. Works like a charm!

Comment: I tried this message, but the stage.orientation property is still unavailable. did I miss a SWC somewhere?